# how to indicate a node of a dictionary in this code (python)?

Tags: python-2.7

when I use this code I get this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/newt.py", line 37, in 
    printTree(tree,tree[''][0])
KeyError: ''

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import codecs
def toTree(expression):
tree = dict()
msg =""
stack = list()
for char in expression:
    if(char == '('):
        stack.append(msg)
        msg = ""
    elif char == ')':
        parent = stack.pop()
        if parent not in tree:
            tree[parent] = list()
        tree[parent].append(msg)
        msg = parent
    else:
        msg += char
return tree

def printTree(tree, node):
   if node not in tree:
    return 
print '%s->%s' % (node, ' '.join(child for child in tree[node])) 
for child in tree[node]:
    printTree(tree, child)

file1=codecs.open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\rxml.txt','r','utf_8') 
expression=file1.read()
tree = toTree(expression)
printTree(tree,tree[''][0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using keys()

> The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the
>   keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it
>   sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it).

Reference: [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Change `printTree(tree,tree[''][0])` to:
`printTree(tree,tree.keys())`

and change printTree function to:

```
def printTree(tree, nodes):
    # loop through nodes (keys)
    for node in nodes:
        if node not in tree:
            return

        print '%s->%s' % (node, ''.join(child for child in tree[node])) 
        for child in tree[node]:
            printTree(tree, child)
```

I think that is what you need.

Comment: Great! you're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer. @عبيرعبدالعزيز